# XMLParser error in objective c, Start tag expected, '<' not found?

Tags: iphone, web-services, xml-parsing, sudzc

in my application i tried to send a web service request in the NSString format. i used sudzc to generate web service . but, when i send the request, i got an error showing

```
Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
Bad Request

  Error Domain=CXMLErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CXMLErrorDomain error 1.)"^
```

here is my sending string which is in xml format,,

```
 NSString *string=[NSString stringWithString:@"<request><ClosingDate>06-Sep-2012</ClosingDate><ProductName>Document Management Software</ProductName><ProductID>3</ProductID><CurrencyID>3</CurrencyID></request>"];
```

but the error shows '<' not found,
i dont know exactly what the error is?
need some help

**EDIT**

I USED SUDZC TO GENERATE WEB SERVICE

```
 MFLCommonServices *services1=[MFLCommonServices service];

 NSString *request=[NSString stringWithString:@"<request><ClosingDate>06-Sep-2012</ClosingDate><ProductName>Document Management Software</ProductName><ProductID>3</ProductID><CurrencyID>3</CurrencyID></request>"];

 [services1 CreateRequest:self action:@selector(CreateRequestHandler:) Email:@"xxxxx"  Password:@"xxxxxx" Token:@"xxxxxx" Request:request];
```

Comment: Perhaps your web service expects the XML to start with a XML declaration, e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: @MartinR but, when i tried with some text (not in xml format) , it successfully received by web service.

Comment: I don't know what your webservice expects. Did you try if adding the XML declaration helps?

Comment: When you send the string, you first turned it into a NSData object, right?

Comment: @DavidH no, i just tried to send the NSString object, bcs my service takes the value as string - (SoapRequest*) CreateRequest: (id) _target action: (SEL) _action Request: (NSString*)

Comment: @MartinR my web service expects NSString object, see the service      - (SoapRequest*) CreateRequest: (id) _target action: (SEL) _action
Request: (NSString*)

Comment: I'm no XML expert, but does the ProductName need quotes? What happens if you try to use a name of just 'Document' without the spaces? Did you try prefixing your string as @MartinR suggested with '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'?

Comment: @DavidH yes i tried , i think the issue is related with the xml format. i googled and found that this might be because of backslash present in the xml format. any idea?

Comment: You could try adding a '\' in front of each '/'. But this is just guessing - somehow you need to find out more about the service and framework you are using.

Comment: @VishnuRaj: There is no backslash in you XML, so that cannot be a problem. Can you post the code how you send the XML string to the server?